# How can i convert image buffer to photo to upload to Cloudinary?

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

How can I use the buffer to upload to Cloudinary as an image. In the buffer using Sharp, I am specifying it is a jpeg. I don't want to save it in the server, so I am proccesing the image, and sending it through the req object

```
exports.resizeUserPhoto = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.file) return next();

  req.file.filename = `user-${req.user.id}-${Date.now()}.jpeg`;

  const processedImage = await sharp(req.file.buffer)
    .resize(150, 150)
    .toFormat("jpeg")
    .jpeg({ quality: 90 })
    .toBuffer();

  //saving the buffer to a new file object
  req.file.processedImage = processedImage;

  next();
};
```

```
exports.updateMe = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
if (req.file) {
    console.log(req.file.processedImage); //returns <Buffer ....... >
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.processedImage, {
      use_filename: true,
      folder: `${req.user.id}/profile/`
    });
    filteredBody.photo = result.url;
  }
}
```

*** Update:
I later found out that it can also be done using DataUri, but somehow read in forums that it slows down the server... which I don't know if its true or not.

Also, most of my problem is with this method: **cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream**. It says that it returns a promise, which is not true.

I asked the question in Cloudinary's forum. I will post answer here.

Comment: Use [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please give me more details? You mean using: btoa()?

Comment: Read [this](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/issues/130) thread for how to use stream/buffer to work with `Cloudinary`.

Comment: let me give a check! thanks.

Comment: I will update my post for you to see new results @Xaqron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
exports.updateMe = catchAsync((req, res, next) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (req.file) {
      // console.log(req.file.processedImage.toString('base64'));
      cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload_stream({ resource_type: 'raw' }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          console.log(`Upload succeed: ${res}`);
          // filteredBody.photo = result.url;
          resolve(res);
        }
      }).end(req.file.processedImage);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I tried passing the buffer, because it is not included in your code, before the { resource_type: 'raw' }, but it tells me: TypeError callback is not a function. I am currently rethinking on using cloudinary!

Comment: The last thing I am thinking, but I don't know if it is going to make my server more costly, is saving the file => uploading to cloudinary => deleting afterwards with node fs

Comment: Saving file is not a good idea and unnecessary. `cloudinary` is Ok, you have a misconception about image, buffer and text. Image is bunch of bytes (with values 0-255) either as a file or stored in a buffer. The problem is for some purposes you cannot use all 0-255 values that's why you covert an image (buffer/saved on harddisk) to text (usually base64 encoded). You should look for `cloudinary` examples for uploading from buffer as my answer is. This code may not work I just included the useful parts from the link into your code.

Comment: It worked! I need one last favor please. upload_stream returns a promise already. How can I convert it to a async/await function?

Comment: If a function returns `Promise` then it is `async/await` ready. Make the outer function (updateMe) `async` and `await` on `upload_stream` returned value. To handle errors call `const result = await upload_stream(...)` inside a `try/catch`.

Comment: You are very talented @GabrielMartinez. Invest on understanding how things work (i.e. how callbacks, promises and async/await are related and why JavaScript needs such concept in first place).

Comment: Thank you! I was doing to the correct things. I just misread the docs. Thought I was supposed to pass some values, and what it was really telling is that i should expect those values.